# Android Studio New Project

Tags: java, android

I just installed Android Studio to start writing my first app, however after starting a new project, it throws this error:

> 'class se.expertsystem.intellij.CrossClassLoaderKey overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z [Plugin: AspectWerkz plugin]'

The project won't start.  What should I do?

Comment: Your setup is probably corrupted. Try uninstalling the IDE and reinstall it.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it hassnt worked

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows/Mac/Linux? x64 or x32? Do you have more details about what happened?

Comment: i am using windows 8, 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve the issue by going to the sdk manager and updating all the plugins of the package. I restarted the computer, after that, the studio package was able to run